# Как разбить на колонки меню в yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Нужно разбить на колонки меню, сделал вот так

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i < 2; $i++) : ?>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
     <?= $this->getMenu($nav['childs']) ?>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

но в результате все повторяется
вот код меню

```
<li class="root">
    <?php if($nav['parent_id'][0] == 0) : ?>
        <?= yii\helpers\Html::a($nav['title'], ['/'.$nav['alias']]) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(isset($nav['childs'])) : ?>
    <div class="main-drop-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="row">
            <?php for($i = 1; $i < 2; $i++) : ?>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <?= $this->getMenu($nav['childs']) ?>
                </div>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Какое меню? Не понял вопроса. По коду, элемент выведется 1 раз, т.к. цикл сработает 1 раз. Если нужно больше, нужно менять условие цикла.

Comment: Делаю виджет меню, в представление передается массив с уже готовой деревом меню $nav, нужно разбить дочерние меню на колонки

Comment: Цикл for($i = 1; $i < 2; $i++) выполнится всего 1 раз. Вам нужно получить количество элементов цикла, например $cntChilds = count($nav['childs']); и добавить значение в условие цикла for($i = 1; $i <= $cntChilds; $i++)